# DataGridComboBoxColumn Binding to a List<String>

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, combobox

I have a WPF application that contains a datagrid. The datagrid is bound to my object OrderBlock which contains a List of type Orders.

```
<DataGrid DataContext="{Binding OrderBlock}"
                  Name="dataGridOrdersGood" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}"
```

This works fine and displays nicely in my datagrid. There is one property (StatusGood) in my List though that I would like to display as a combobox where there can be only two values, "Send" or "Hold".

So I was trying to bind the combobox values to the List StatusList as shown below. Then trying to bind the actual value to my object.

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public List<string> StatusList;

    // constructor
    public ViewModel() 
    {
        StatusList = new List<string>();
        StatusList.Add("Hold");
        StatusList.Add("Send");
    }
 }

<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Status Good" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding StatusList}"    SelectedValuePath="{Binding StatusGood}"/>
```

However nothing is displayed other than a empty combobox. I do not understand why at the very least my combobox is not showing the value of my object? I am providing a list so again I do not understand why it's not showing anything.

I'm new to WPF and must struggling to understand it. I have referenced but obviously not fully understand it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn.aspx

Any help would be great!
Thanks,
M

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution, where your List is a ComboBoxItem, would this be possible?

Here is my sample XAML:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="myGridTest">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Text" Binding="{Binding MyText}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Combobox">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboList}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

My C#-Class

```
public class Test
{
    private string _MyText;
    private IList<ComboBoxItem> _ComboList;

    public Test()
    {
        _MyText = "Test 123";

        _ComboList = new List<ComboBoxItem>();

        _ComboList.Add(new ComboBoxItem() { Content = "Next", IsSelected = true });
        _ComboList.Add(new ComboBoxItem() { Content = "Prev." });
    }

    public IList<ComboBoxItem> ComboList
    {
        get { return _ComboList; }
        set { _ComboList = value; }
    }

    public string MyText
    {
        get { return _MyText; }
        set { _MyText = value; }
    }
}
```

And for Testing:

```
    List<Test> cList = new List<Test>();
    cList.Add(new Test());
    cList.Add(new Test());
    cList.Add(new Test());
    cList.Add(new Test());
    cList.Add(new Test());

    myGridTest.ItemsSource = cList;
```

I hope this help you...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like DataGridComboBoxColumn->SelectedItemBinding has to be in your case:

```
 SelectedItemBinding="{Binding StatusGood}"
```

and you have to set also ItemsSource property of the DataGridComboBoxColumn and modify your ViewModel for providing combo values to use property(StatusList) instead of field.

VM:

```
public class ViewModel 
{
    public List<string> StatusList { get; set; }

    // constructor
    public ViewModel()
    {
        StatusList = new List<string>();
        StatusList.Add("Hold");
        StatusList.Add("Send");
    }

}
```

XAML:

```
 <DataGrid.Resources>
        <local:ViewModel x:Key="ComboItems"  />
 </DataGrid.Resources>

<DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedItemBinding="{Binding StatusGood}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=StatusList, Source={StaticResource ComboItems}}" >
```