# How to bind List<string> data with DataGridComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridviewcombobox

**Xaml Code below :**

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Select Type" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboList}"/>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Select Type2">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ComboList}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

ComboList is just `List<string>`

Using DataTemplate, Combobox ItemsSource Binding is worked.
But, DataGridComboBoxColumn is not worked.

How to bind List data with DataGridComboBoxColumn?

Comment: please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18580483/1531476

Comment: @ankit_sharma Thank you :) Could I ask more something? Why should I use StaticResource for DataGridComboBoxColumn Binding? General Combobox don't need it. Already DataGrid sets its ItemsSource.